# Make search page with Taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I am fairly new to Drupal and i'm working on a already existing site, so i'm facing a lot of issues. I need to make a page that shows nodes of a certain type, it has to contain the following features:

- It has to show a search form on top of the page (the site is using the Apache Solr module) to search only content of one type
- It has to show nodes grouped under their taxonomy fields. There are 3 vocabularies and nodes have to be listed for each vocabulary, for example:

Vocabulary 1

Term 1

Node 1

Node 2

Vocabulary 2

Term 2

Node 1

Node 3

Nodes can be shown more than once for each Taxonomy term

I know i'm asking a lot and probably the question is borderline with the stackexchange rules, but i have tried a lot of modules and solutions (for example using the Views module) but i just can't get what i want no matter how i try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- to reduce results by the content type, when you set up the view, filter by content-type, and select the appropriate content type. If it already exists, use a FILTER CRITERIA and use content-type (I believe this can also be accomplished through the search settings)
- to group: set format to fields, add the taxonomy term to the fields list to group by (you can hide from display if desired), click on Settings under FORMAT. There you can group by any field currently in the view
- for Solr, take a look at [Apache Solr Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views) Module and the related documentation for implementing this functionality.

Apache Solr Views:

> This module provides a Views integration to the Apache Solr Search
>   Integration project. It provides the views plugins and handlers needed
>   to be able to create a view that fetches its results from Apachesolr
>   index, without hitting the database.